# Writing Data into MySQL Table with Python

Tags: python, mysql, database

I am trying to output data into a MySQL Database.
I can create the database and connect to it (after a lot of problems).

Now I want to write Data into the database. I use the following Code:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO AmazonSalesRank(Artist_Name) VALUES(artist_name)")
```

This seems to work if I put a real value instead of

```
artist_name
```

for example

```
"Bon Jovi"
```

as soon as I have the variable it does not.
Is the code wrong? Any idea?

Edit: I have also just seen that the data is pushed into several rows and not one... Do I have to combine the statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`artist_name` here is just a literal string. And try:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO AmazonSalesRank(Artist_Name) VALUES(%s)", [artist_name])
```

Comment: Give the following error: _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/title>)' at line 1")

Comment: Sorry to give you a wrong answer. I have edited my answer and you may retry it. @user2401772

Comment: This is it. Do you also know how to add several variables at a time?

Comment: For example, `cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(a, b, c) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)", [A, B, C]` and there is also `executemany` you can use to execute several insertions one time. @user2401772

Comment: Already found it myself. Just separate with "," in the brackets. Sweet! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score -1):

To use a variable like artist_name instead of a string like "Bon Jovi" you should concatenate the string properly, like:

```
"The "+artist_name+" is cool"
```

would result in "The Bon Jovi is cool"

using "The "+"Bon Jovi"+" is cool" would result in the same string as 
"The ""Bon Jovi"" is cool" without the + sign, which is what is happening here, you are implicitly concatenating strings.

So you should use something like:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO AmazonSalesRank("+Artist_Name+") VALUES(artist_name)")
```

for more on string formatting take a look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting

Comment: Not sure what you want to tell me exactly. And: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Ahhh... Maybe you think that I want to have "Artist Name Bon Jovi" in the field?! That is not the case. I just want to have "Bon Jovi" in the Artist_Name field.

Comment: I fixed the typo, the + sign should be after Artist_Name, but it was after the quote

Comment: Still not Working: NameError: name 'Artist_Name' is not defined.

Comment: you should define your variables with the value you need, for the sake of the example add Artist_Name="Bon Jovi" before the query

Comment: −1: using string concatenation to assemble SQL queries exposes you to SQL injection attacks.